# Optimize Blender 3.2 + nvidia GTX 1080 3D Manager and Blender Cycles Setup

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

nvidia GeForce GTX 1080 Control Panel has a 3D Manager per application, in this case Blender 3.2.
I'm not sure what changes if any need to be made and seeking advice on how to optimize for this particular GPU.
Is it better to change 3D settings only for Blender or globally, will other renders such as Marmoset Toolbag 4, KeyShot Pro, also benefit form these settings? I use this Computer for 2D graphics (Photoshop, Corel, etc.) and don't want global settings optimized for 3D to affect them.
[image: nvidiaGTX1080#DSettings]

Comment: I've not found a need to adjust the settings for Blender for GTX 1080 and would suggest only doing so if you're seeing problems and want to see if disabling a feature fixes them.

Comment: I don't get it why there are votes to close the question. Seems to me like a simple question with a simple answer. No need to optimize anything. That's it.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Because this site is about problems that occur with using Blender's tools and functions. Otimizing GPU settings in the OS or other external software like Nvidia Control Panel are not considered on topic on this site, see [help center](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I would consider this question to be about using Blender, specifically about setting it up. I have seen many questions here about using GPUs with Blender and see nothing wrong with this one. It's not asking for hardware recommendations, just about what needs to be done for Blender to work as intended. That's the way I understand the question anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is simply no need to "Optimize" anything. Leave everything at defaults and Blender will work fine.

Comment: Thanks Martynas, Good to know. as an example, there are settings typical of 3D applications, "AA" and  "AO"  on the graphics card when would these settings be changed and be used? Why are these setting included to be changed and for what situation and purpose?

Comment: You do not need to worry about them ever. The settings are pretty much useless as software or games use features of graphics cards as they are needed. Probably if something goes wrong, in some rare hypothetical situation they might have some meaning as you could disable some feature from there. I have never seen such a situation in my life yet and chances are the real solution to that problem would be something else anyway. The way I see it, they are probably there to make you feel better and more in control after spending a lot of money on a GPU.